# mysql escape getsqlvaluestring AccID

Tags: php, mysql, session, escaping

In various mysql queries, the end part of the query string is:

```
" WHERE UserID = " . $AccID
```

where

```
$AccID = $_SESSION['UID'];
```

and UserID is the respecting bigint column in the specific table of the db.

So my question is : do I need to escape the `$AccID` like this `GetSQLValueString($AccID, "text")` just to be on the safe side, or there is no need to, since it's not taken from a user input ?

p.s. `$_SESSION['UID']` is set during the login procedure, after a successful authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should escape it. You should not database-escape it when you put it into `$_SESSION` (you might want to use it for other purposes), but before inserting into the query.

Your best bet would be though to use parameterized SQL instead of always escaping and building your queries through string concatenation. Get familiar with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). [For a better world](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Comment: Yes, I do not escape variables when i put it in the $_SESSION, only in query strings.The reason for escaping it despite not being a user input variable but DB only, is: better safe than sorry ?

Comment: @MIrrorMirror Better safe than sorry :). But consider those parameterized queries, I sleep better since I use them. `mysql_` functions are old and will become deprecated for a reason.

Comment: Tbe coding horror link was illuminating, as I understand with paremeterized sql there is no need any more for escaping since it's done internally. However one particular comment seemed to make a valid point against it performance wise. see a comment by "Chris on May 14, 2008 8:26 AM"

Comment: @MirrorMirror I don't see how that comment has anything to do with performance. Also, I don't think there is any valid point against parameterized queries. Even if they were a bit slower (they are not AFAIK). Concatenated SQL queries should not have spread, but they did, now they must be stopped. Most sites on the web have some SQL injection vulnerability. Even if you are escaping, you can make mistakes and forget some.